# What technical color space is OpenEXR rendering in Blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-passes

I’m rendering my project as an OpenEXR sequence and, when I go to composite this over my footage, to be exactly accurate, I need to both convert the Gamut from what it originally was rendered at, and to what I want for the final result (Which in my case, is sRGB). But I don’t know what technical color space OpenEXR is in Blender. **What color space is OpenEXR?**

Comment: Hi :). I'm no expert but afaik EXRs use the unconverted camera color space, since they're meant for a scene-referred workflow https://www.filmriot.com/blog/scene-referred-vs-display-referred/#:~:text=A%20scene%2Dreferred%20workflow%20is,space%20to%20display%20color%20space.